# Should I do an explicit cast when passing an object?

Tags: c#, casting

My piece of code for test :

```
static void TestMethod(IBingo obj)
{
// Access the property
Console.WriteLine($"The value is {obj.Point}" );
}
...
class Yankee : IBingo {
// Some stuff
}
// inside Main
Yankee obj = new Yankee();
if(obj is IBingo)
{
// So the object does have the IBingo functionality!
TestMethod((IBingo)obj); 
// Is this implicit casting recommended for any reason?
TestMethod(obj); // Runs perfectly fine
}
```

My initial guess is that this cast is only useful when a proper check is not
done so that program would throw an exception.

Comment: Did you mean to write `TestMethod((IBingo)test)` and `TestMethod(test)`?

Comment: @canton7 Yes. I guess there is no difference in this case..

Comment: you dont need the explicit casting here, implicit casting just works

Comment: I don't expect the code to compile in this case. As far as I know, making a implicit cast explicit doesn't affect it very much.

Comment: @Vishnu there's no casting involved, `test` *is* a variable whose type is `IBingo`

Comment: @canton7 Oops I misread your first comment.  I made a small change to my code. This is just a learning exercise.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the fact that you question has completely changed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real point to either call because `test` is already cast to `IBingo`. You could write :

```
if(obj is IBingo test)
{
    TestMethod(test); 
}
```

You're using the pattern matching form of `if` which means that the block will be entered *only* if `obj` can be cast to `IBingo`. When that happens, the result of the cast will be stored in the `test` variable. That variable will be in scope only inside that block.

That pattern matching code is the equivalent of :

```
var test = obj as IBingo;
if (test!=null)
{
    TestMethod(test);
}
```

**Update**

The modified code doesn't need any casting because the `Yankee` class *is* an `IBingo` implementation.

If it weren't, it would depend on whether there was an implicit or explicit cast defined from `Yankee` to `IBingo`. The `as` operator would work in any case.

Comment: I made a small change to my code. Could you take that into account?

Comment: @sjsam that's not a *small* change, it changed from pattern matching to type checking. Use the pattern matching form instead. WIth the change you made, yes, you *may* need to explicitly cast if there's no implicit cast. Of course, since `Yankee` implements IBingo, it *is* IBingo and no casting is required

Comment: Hmm.. I am quite new to C#. I was experimenting with the features. Hmm so pattern matching is the suggested approach here? In what way is it better than casting approach?

Comment: Also, regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519096/should-i-do-an-implicit-cast-when-passing-an-object#comment97743394_55519211), pattern matching with `is` keyword came new in C# 7. Am I right? Was there a standard practice before that?

Answer (score 2):

In your updated code, `Yankee` is *always* an `IBingo`. The compiler knows this, and it simplifies your code to:

```
if (obj != null)
{
    TestMethod(obj);
    TestMethod(obj);
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQDk4BstWFiAEQHsBzMY4gEwBoqQBqAHwAEAGAAhYEYBuAWABQLAExshLAMxcRXbgHYOAbyEc1XaSwAsHALIAKAJpQAdgGsIEDsWAArAJTLV6lwEswHfTdsdXyDgCSAEKuJqTE9kIAkFFKHNExACooMLoQMAAW1Pr6waHh9t72vPGCMVHJyKnpWVRedsXOLmoAvtFtgi5NHAAOCK4AbrBW2hyV1ZnZeWHEHMCOcR0dEtKhMBAIYFAAxlbT4cocy8KassbmlhwggSEzhx1AA==).

As you can see, it reduced the type check down to a null check, and it removed your pointless cast.

Because you're calling `TestMethod` which takes an `IBingo`, your `Yankee` will *always* be cast down to an `IBingo` when you call the method. Adding in an extra cast yourself is pointless.

---

Old answer (from your pre-edited question)

Assuming you meant to write (as indicated in the comments)

```
if (obj is IBingo test)
{
    TestMethod((IBingo)test); 
    TestMethod(test);
}
```

There is no difference. The variable `test` is already of type `IBingo` -- there isn't even an implicit conversion here. The compiler removes the cast in the first case, so both lines become `TestMethod(test)`. [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQDk4BstWFiAEQHsBzMY4gEwBoqQBqAHwAEAGAAhYEYBuAWABQLAExshLAMxcRXbgHYOAbyEc1XaSwAsHALIAKYsABWEAMYwOR4wEplq9Y4CWYDoZMcnyDgEkAQk4AdqTEHDAoMDZCAJDRShwxsQAqEboQMAAW1Pr6/kEhNuHIkbwJgrHRKcVpmdlFJQ6OagC+Ma2Cjo0cAA4ITgBusBBcOlUwNVlUuQHBocB28e3tEtJB4QhgUGbDebPKHM1AA==)

Comment: `The compiler knows this` in compile time and hence it has an opportunity to optimize. Right? Brilliant ! What if this information is not available in compile time. What if the interface is in an assembly I happen to import? Would the compiler still figure out this information??

Comment: @sjsam You start with a `Yankee`. For that code to compile, the compiler has to know the definition of the `Yankee` type. If it knows that, it knows whether `Yankee` implements `IBingo`. If you start off with an object of type `object`, so the compiler doesn't know whether it's an `IBingo`, a `Yankee` or anything else, then see the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Implicit Conversion** 
An implicit conversion always exists from a class to any one of its direct or indirect base classes or interfaces. No special syntax is necessary because a derived class always contains all the members of a base class.

```c#
Derived d = new Derived();  
Base b = d; // Always OK.
```

**Explicit Conversion** If a conversion cannot be made without a risk of losing information, the compiler requires that you perform an explicit conversion, which is called a cast

```c#
// Create a new derived type.  
Giraffe g = new Giraffe();  

// Implicit conversion to base type is safe.  
Animal a = g;  

// Explicit conversion is required to cast back  
// to derived type. Note: This will compile but will  
// throw an exception at run time if the right-side  
// object is not in fact a Giraffe.  
Giraffe g2 = (Giraffe) a;
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask what each type of conversion is. The question was whether one or the other form was better and the answer *in this pattern matching case* is "neither"

Comment: It sounded to me like the OP was confused about when to use a cast @PanagiotisKanavos I was providing insight

Comment: that's the actual confusion. None is needed because *test*, not *obj*, should be used